# Splitting arrays - discarding keys that are below a certain value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, lets say that the keys are: 100, 512, 610, 21, 176, 64. I can always sort the array if needed.

I want to get rid of the array values that have a key below a certain value, say below 110. That would get rid of 100, 21, and 64.

I would like to do this WITHOUT using a foreach. Is there a function that I can use, where I can maybe sort the array, find the splice point, and from there delete that chanck all in one swoop?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with foreach? Is this requirement objective? The solution would take 3 meaningful lines

Comment: I just don't like using a loop if I can avoid it. Besides, I figured there might be a way to tell PHP "Hey, you see that position right there? Keep everything above that, throw everything else away". =)

Comment: "I just don't like using a loop if I can avoid it" --- omg. Keep in mind the first programming rule: programs are written for developers, not for compilers. So write the code that is easy to understand, not that takes "less" lines to implement

Comment: It's not about lines. I think about performance, but not only that, but I like to try new stuff. Using a loop would be easy; a no-brainer. But seeing the solution posted below introduces me to new concepts I may not have thought of myself.

Comment: "Using a loop would be easy; a no-brainer." --- writing the code that is easy to maintain is an art, not a "no-braining". And performance in 99.99% is not a thing you should think about in such trivial cases.

Comment: "But seeing the solution posted below introduces me to new concepts I may not have thought of myself." --- the solution below is 4 trivial functions combined together. It is not magic, it is just 4 well-documented functioncs

Comment: @zerk Oh come on, lay off the guy. The functional approach to solving this can indeed be a good experience. Even if not the best solution... :)

Comment: @deceze: I don't write functional code, but when I do - I use (erlang|haskell|F#|...) ;-)

Comment: @zerk Right, so this is "functional programming lite", for people who can't afford the real experience. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loop is seriously the most straight forward way to do it. For the fun of it though, here's a solution without (visible) loop:

```
$array = array_intersect_keys(
    $array,
    array_flip(array_filter(
        array_keys($array),
        function ($key) { return $key > 110; }
    ))
);
```

Maybe you should use a loop instead.

Comment: Definitely loop is better. This "oneliner" is really difficult to understand :-) +1 for being tricky though

Comment: I'm interested in the performance of this vs loop when it comes to potentially hundreds of rows. I'll test that out tomorrow, but for now you get a +1 for cleverness =)

Comment: @Ryan: `foreach` will be faster. If you don't see any obvious loop structure in the code - it doesn't mean there are no any. In this sample I could think of at least **4** loops

Comment: @Ryan A loop which `unsets` any unwanted keys is the most performant, simply because it does the checking and unsetting in one iteration. There's no other language construct in PHP that I know of that expresses this operation other than a good old loop. Anything else will need several iterations to come to the same result. It's good fun to play around with the functional way of doing things though... ;)